# Better way to declare string enums and use them - Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

```
 enum ROUTES {
  REQUEST_OTP = 'REQUEST_OTP',
  LOGIN = 'LOGIN',
}

export const urls: { [key: string]: string } = {
  [ROUTES.REQUEST_OTP]: '/v1/auth/otp',
  [ROUTES.LOGIN]: '/v1/auth/login',
};

export function getUrl(route: string) {
  return BASE_URL + urls[route];
}
```

Is there a better way to write ROUTES enum rather than repeatedly writing string literals next to it?

There seems to be a repetition of code in the my code writing the string enums.

Trying out mapped types:

```
 type ROUTE_KEY = 'REQUEST_OTP' | 'LOGIN';

export const urls: { [key: string]: string } = {
  REQUEST_OTP: '/v1/auth/request-otp',
  LOGIN: '/v1/auth/login/?version=v2',
};

export function getUrl(route: ROUTE_KEY) {
  return BASE_URL + urls[route];
}
```

Comment: I usually use a config.ts file to store such urls, and load these to the ENV. So, the default values will be in the config and it can be overridden by setting the env var too.

Comment: You'll want to use `{ [key: ROUTE_KEY]: string }`

Comment: Or even better, `type ROUTE_KEY = keyof typeof urls;` (with `urls` being declared `as const`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to avoiding redundancy in this situation is to compute your types from your values while leveraging type inference. Every JavaScript expression has a corresponding TypeSript type.
As Bergi metioned, we can obtain the type from a value by using the `typeof` operator in type position. Together with the `keyof` type operator we use this to compute a union type consisiting of all property keys in `urls`.

```
export const urls = {
  EQUEST_OTP: '/v1/auth/request-otp',
  LOGIN: '/v1/auth/login/?version=v2'
};

export type RouteKey = keyof typeof urls;

export function getUrl(route: RouteKey) {
  return BASE_URL + urls[route];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIQIIGUBRAfQFUAlAGQC55MYBLFAcwG4BYAKC5AA8AHJDCzJ0WAK4wIaeAF54Aby7x4hAIqlC+ACrEA8toAKtAOQB6AG4BGM1HEYAFmbgBHcSEwBaJBn4mANMrwlHoA4gCSAHKmljZ2jmYQSMxMZgD8FiAwaAyoshYATAFcAL5cPAJCWBgAnvwI5Ej2IADSIDVy8ADW7UgAZvC19f3wktIc3Jx8gsLwfeIoYBi5KPDMIBikUgAUME0YILSNzW01AJSKQXAYkqt4RGRU8ADUo1JoANp7zQC6E2WcIA)

In the above, we used `typeof` type operator to obtain the type of the value `urls`,  which is

```
{
  REQUEST_OTP: string,
  LOGIN: string
}
```

We then used the `keyof` type operator to compute a union type consisting of the property keys of the that type, which is

```
'REQUEST_OTP' | 'LOGIN'
```

Notice how the variable `urls` has no type annotation. The use of type inference not only increases brevity but also results in a far stronger type than `{ [key: string]: string }`.

Alternately, we can actually could do without declaring the type alias `RouteKey` and just write

```
export function getUrl(route: keyof typeof urls) {
  return BASE_URL + urls[route];
}
```

Comment: I want to point out that we should be appending the urls with `URL` here is the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL); instead of using string concatenation, like `new URL(urls[route], BASE_URL)`. If the person passes in an invalid URL, it will throw a `TypeError` object error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if this is better, because you're not specific about what is bad with your current sample. However, this is how I would write this:

```js
type RouteKey = 'request-otp' | 'login';


export const urls: { [key: RouteKey]: string } = {
  'request-otp': '/v1/auth/otp',
  'login:': '/v1/auth/login',
};


export function getUrl(route: RouteKey) {
  return BASE_URL + urls[route];
}
```

Comment: This results in an error. Index signatures cannot be a union type. The correct type would be `{ [P in RouteKey]: string }`